# MarkLogic XSLT transformer does not transform properly

Tags: xml, xslt, marklogic

I invoked below transformation query to transform the XML with XSLT.

```
xdmp:xslt-invoke("example.xsl", $doc, (), ())
```

example.xsl contains below contents.

```
 <xsl:template match="CaseRef">
 <xsl:variable xmlns:encoder="xalan://java.net.URLEncoder" name="urlEncodedCit"
         select="encoder:encode( substring( string(@href),2))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$urlEncodedCit"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But the MarkLogic Query Console does not transform properly. It seems to me that, the file is not transformed correctly.

But the transformation is working in saxonEE and Xalan.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Well you are using a proprietary extension mechanism, if it works with one XSLT processor or even two there is no guarantee it will work with other. I am not familiar with Marklogic, if their docs don't tell anything about calling into Java from XSLT then I would start trying to debug it with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="function-available('encoder:encode')" xmlns:encoder="xalan://java.net.URLEncoder"/>`. If that does return false then the Xalan based mechanims is not supported.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Don't just tell us something fails, tell us HOW it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the call to java.net.URLEncoder with a call to the standard XPath 2.0 function escape-html-uri().

Comment: Thanks a lot. The XPath 2.0 function helped me.

Comment: The error message should have been something like `[XSLT] XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function encoder:encode()`. That should be a good clue, and adding it here may help anyone googling error messages. MarkLogic doesn't implement xalan extensions. You can use standard functions, or use MarkLogic extensions, or implement your own functions in XSLT or XQuery.